# How to access user_location in Facebook Login?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm requesting the permissions like this:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_location"], from: self) { (result, error) in
```

Upon signup I can see it is asking me for the user_location:

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, user_location"], httpMethod: "GET")
                request?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                    if ((error) != nil)
                    {
                        // Process error
                        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print(result!)
                    }
                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
```

})

But it seems the key is missing:

```
Error: Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_location) on node type (User), com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            "fbtrace_id" = Hp3weSaqfI7;
            message = "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_location) on node type (User)";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}})
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

But according to the docs, it should be on the user object. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But according to the docs, it should be on the user object.

No, it should not.

You are confusing the name of the permission - `user_location` - with the name of the actual field of the `user` object - `location`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/:

> `location`
>   Page
>   The person's current location as entered by them on their profile. This field is not related to check-ins